# How to enable Rhino (or any JavaScript Engine) in CQ 5.6?

Tags: osgi, aem, rhino

I have some custom logic where I need to evaluate a simple boolean expression. In my IDE I have some unit tests that run fine, but when I'm trying to use it on my CQ 5.6.1 instance, the `ScriptEngineManager` can't find a JavaScript engine. Though this should be part of a standard java installation on any environment.

```
ScriptEngineManager sef = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine se = sef.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
```

In the pom I have the following which usually helps:

```
<Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>
```

Usually some system libraries aren't exposed in OSGi when you don't put it into the bootdelegation in the `sling.properties`, but this didn't work either:

```
org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=org.w3c.*,com.sun.script.*,com.yourkit.*, ${org.apache.sling.launcher.bootdelegation}
```

What else could I try?

**EDIT:**
Also regarding my comment to Christians answer. I found out that there should be a service in the OSGi:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/bundles/scripting/javascript/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/javascript/internal/RhinoJavaScriptEngineFactory.java

But when I try to reference it with the following code, my servlet isn't active anymore:

```
@Reference
private transient ScriptEngineFactory sef = null;
```

So it seems it can't inject the factory for some reason. I've seen there could be more than one service implementing this interface, how would I target the correct one (linked above)?

**EDIT2:**
I now even tried to reference the Rhino factory directly:

```
@Reference(target = "(component.name=org.apache.sling.scripting.javascript.internal.RhinoJavaScriptEngineFactory)")
private transient ScriptEngineFactory sef = null;
```

With this my servlet tells me it is satisfied:

```
["Satisfied","Service Name: javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory","Target Filter: (component.name=org.apache.sling.scripting.javascript.internal.RhinoJavaScriptEngineFactory)","Multiple: single","Optional: mandatory","Policy: static","Bound Service ID 2004 (org.apache.sling.scripting.javascript.internal.RhinoJavaScriptEngineFactory)"]
```

But if I access my servlet it doesn't get triggered and the SlingDefaultServlet takes over. Without the above `@Reference` it is accessible, so it has to do something with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost a whole day of trial and error I found 2 major problems:

First: My compiler plugin was set to use 1.8; I had to revert that to 1.6 so my `maven-scr-plugin` would create proper manifests again and injection of OSGi services actually works:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have to investigate later how it would be possible to increase that to at least 1.7 (I tried but didn't work either).

**Second and the actual answer for my question is simple:**

```
@Reference
private transient ScriptEngineManager sem = null;
```

Also I had to use `javascript` instead of `JavaScript` for the `getEngineByName` method from the manager. To see what is registered for the engine, you can check out the following path in your OSGi console:

```
/system/console/status-slingscripting
```

There all available `ScriptEngine` are listed with their registered names, extensions and MIME Types.

Answer (score 1):

You need an OSGi capable ScriptEngineManager. See https://devnotesblog.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/scripting-using-jsr-223-in-an-osgi-environment/

Comment: thanks, though I found out that there should be one from org.apache.sling.scripting.javascript available in this case, but still no success. I even added this dependency explicitly to my pom.xml

Comment: I tried it with the classes provided in the blog entry, but now they complain that they don't know BundleContext in findFactoryCandidates:
org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught Throwable java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/BundleContext